# Blender sculpting mask tool not working

Tags: mesh, interface, sculpting, masking

For the past few days I've been learning Blender and today I'm trying out sculpting by just using all the tools and trying to make a simple face.

However I want to extrude out the neck as I did make a low poly face. At first it worked perfectly when I masked the neck area and used the snake hook tool to extrude it out. However, my mask was not how I wanted it to be so I removed it and tried masking again.

I might've pressed some wrong keys trying to remove the mask and when I select the mask tool again it shows a grey circle (not sure if its supposed to be grey or not) but doesn't actually draw the black region over my model. When I restart Blender it is still the same. Does anyone have a clue on what I might have done wrong here and how I can return it to default? The strength is not set to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to bring up the mask and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to clear it. Works for Some.

For me my overlay was off.

Pressing <kbd>A</kbd> will bring up the mask options menu.

Once you draw the mask then press <kbd>A</kbd> and move your mouse quickly to the left (or press <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>) to invert the selection. Then press <kbd>G</kbd> to grab or whatever to move the geometry then press <kbd>A</kbd> and move your mouse quickly to the right (or press <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>6</kbd>) to clear the mask.

Also make sure your overlays are turned on so you can see the mask.

Comment: I haven't found how to show (*turned on*) the overlays in 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found in the top left drop down menu *Sculpt* a check box for *Show Mask*. The hotkey is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Then I figured out I had to apply or turn off the Modifier or else mask, box mask, lasso box, box hide will not work. Hope this helps.

[image]

[image]